# Passing OracleLob as parameter to a function

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net, blob

I want to accomplish a similar thing:

```
try
{
    openConnection();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, IMAGE_BLOB FROM CUSTOMER_IMAGE WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (3026)", conn);
    string pubID = "";
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

    //create the report object
    MemoryStream memStream;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable ImageTable = new DataTable();
    BinaryReader binReader;
    DataRow dr;

    byte[] byteArrName;
    OracleLob blob;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        pubID = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

        // Obtain a LOB
        blob = reader.GetOracleLob(1);

        // Create a byte array of the size of the Blob obtained
        byteArrName = new byte[blob.Length];

        // Read blob data into byte array
        int i = blob.Read(byteArrName, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(blob.Length));

        //Copied the contents of byte array to stream
        memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrName);

        //Create a column of type byte[]
        ImageTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(string)));
        ImageTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("image", typeof(System.Byte[])));

        //Reading the stream which has the blob data
        binReader = new BinaryReader(memStream);
        dr = ImageTable.NewRow();

        dr["id"] = pubID;
        //ReadBytes method to add a byte array of the image stream.
        dr["image"] = binReader.ReadBytes((int)binReader.BaseStream.Length);
        ImageTable.Rows.Add(dr);

        memStream.Close();
        binReader.Close();
    }

    ds.Tables.Add(ImageTable);

    //Creating a temporary dataset which hold the image
    ds.WriteXmlSchema(@Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\temp.xsd");

    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Now, I'll populate that temp.xsd in the Crystal Report such that the image will be displayed dynamically. This is just a sample code I wrote from scratch, but to fit my scenario, I need to get the image that is already in `dtAcctSigner.Rows[0]["IMAGE_BLOB"],` so just wondering if there's any way I can fetch this BLOB just like I fetch in the above code as

```
OracleDataReader.GetOracleLob();
```

For that, I need to pass a column of the datatable(Type-OracleLob) as a parameter to a function like this:

```
Update(dtAcctSigner.Rows[0]["IMAGE_BLOB"]);
```

And the function goes as follows:

```
public void Update(OracleLob a)
{ 
// I want to do take the OracleLob and make into a memorystream and put it into temp.xsd here
}
```

But I get an error:

```
cannot convert 'object' to 'OracleLob'
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to clean up your question then.. also don't post code methods that are empty.. if we are to help you, you have to be a bit more clear / specific as to the issue that you are having.. this is a bit confusing / hard to follow what you are trying to accomplish
Please show full code on how you are passing Update(dtAcctSigner.Rows[iCount1]["SIGNATURE_BLOB"]);
 as well as declaring the datatable

Comment: most people downvote when things are as follows
1. Doesn't show enough research on by the individual
2. Very abstract in nature
3. Is not really a question..etc

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I edited the question, pls take a look at it

Comment: With reader.Read(), this code works fine as sample app. But in the main code, I don't have OracleDataReader, instead, I have DataTable, so, is there anyway I can convert that column(IMAGE_BLOB) as OracleLob?

Comment: if it's declared as int you need to cast it as a byte

Comment: In Oracle table, IMAGE_BLOB is declared as BLOB object. In the code, should I declare the type of the column in the datatable as byte[] or OracleLob?

Comment: I am going to post an example that you can try keep in mind that I am testing this using a Console App

Comment: I don't think that you need a memory Stream but you can read the data in Chunks like I've shown below

Answer (score 0):

```
using(reader)
{
      //Obtain the first row of data.
      reader.Read();
      //Obtain the LOBs (all 3 varieties).
      OracleLob BLOB = reader.GetOracleLob(1);
      ...

      //Example - Reading binary data (in chunks).
      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
      while((actual = BLOB.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) >0)
         Console.WriteLine(BLOB.LobType + 
            ".Read(" + buffer + ", " + buffer.Length + ") => " + actual);

      ...
}
```

I personally would create and add columns to the DataTable this way but it's up to you to try it this way or another way that you know will work

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("ImageTable"); //Create a new DataTable instance.

DataColumn column0 = new DataColumn("id"); //Create the column.
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"); //Type string 

DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("image"); //Create the column.
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //Type byte[] to store image bytes.
column.AllowDBNull = true;
column.Caption = "My Image";

table.Columns.Add(column0); //Add the column to the table.
table.Columns.Add(column1); //Add the column to the table.

Then, add a new row to this table and set the value of the MyImage column.

DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["MyImage"] = <Image byte array>;
tables.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: this code helps me learnt about the chunks. But I'm converting it into a memory stream just because I should make the image writable in CrystalReports in run-time.

Comment: Oh ok I was not aware of that.. I am going to add another example of how I would create the DataTable and assign the Columns below the answer I have above

Comment: I'm taking this into a memory stream and writing it into a temporary xml schema in the hard-disk such that it can be populated into CrystalReports. Also, for using the reader.GetOracleLob, I'm not using OracleDataReader, instead I've this BLOB object in Datatable. So, I need to know how I can convert the column in datatable to oraclelob without OracleDataReader.