# Converting datatable to oracledataReader

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oracle, ado.net

Can I convert a datatable to OracleDataReader like I can convert a DataTable to DataTableReader

```
DataTable.CreateDataReader().
```

Is there any method to generate OracleDataReader out of DataTable?

I really want some suggestions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149618/passing-oraclelob-as-parameter-to-a-function)

Also, tell me if there's a way converting a datatable column to type OracleLob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing OracleLob as parameter to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149618/passing-oraclelob-as-parameter-to-a-function)

Comment: @Blam I only asked that question, Just wanted to know if I can get an answer by asking the question in a different way. I mentioned it in this question, that it is related to "Passing OracleLob as parameter to a function" question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late, but it can help someone.

IDataReader resultBanner = (IDataReader)objDatatable.CreateDataReader();